# Typeerror for file deletion from database in django

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, delete-file

I'm trying to get together code that uploads and deletes photos from a django/bootstrap carousel, as well as a database.  However, I can't seem to get past this error:

```
TypeError at /alzheimers/delete

delete() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Can anyone help me?  I'm kind of a noob at django, and writing this code is like pulling teeth, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code:
Carousel.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load filename %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">


                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    {% for document in documents %}
 <div class="item {% if forloop.first %} active {% endif %}"> 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <li><a href = "{{document.docfile.url}}">{{document.docfile.name}}</a></li>
        <img src = "{{STATIC_URL}}img/{{document|filename}}" >
<p align="center"><form style="text-align:center" action="{% url 'webportal:delete' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
<p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
            <p>{{ form.Document.label_tag }} {{ form.Document.help_text }}</p>
            <p>
                {{ form.Document.errors }}
                {{ form.Document.docfile }}
            </p> 
            <p><input type="submit" value="Delete" /></p>
        </form></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.carousel -->
        </div>
    </div>
<form action="{% url 'webportal:carousel' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
            <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>
            <p>
                {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                {{ form.docfile }}
            </p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
        </form>

</div>
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from webportal.views.authentication import LoginForm
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import settings
from webportal.forms.forms import DocumentForm
from webportal.models import Document, DeleteForm
is_server = True
def delete(request, my_id):
    Deleted=get_object_or_404(Document, docfile=my_id)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=DeleteForm(request.POST, instance=Deleted)
        if form.is_valid():
            Deleted.delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/alzheimers/')
    else:
        form=DeleteForm(instance=Deleted)
    return render_to_response(
        'webportal/index.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form,},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )        

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
def carousel(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/alzheimers/')



else:



 form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form
# Load documents for the list page
documents = Document.objects.all()
#documents=DocumentForm().
# Render list page with the documents and the form
return render_to_response(
    'webportal/index.html',
    {'documents': documents, 'form': form,},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)
```

Models.py:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.ImageField(upload_to='webportal/static/img/')
class DeleteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Document
        fields=[]
```

Forms.py:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.ImageField(label='Select a file', help_text='max. 42 megabytes')
```

urls.py:

url(r'^delete', views.delete, name="delete"),

Comment: You are trying to call your delete view without a `my_id` argument. Can you post the relevant line of your `urls.py`?

Comment: @ Selcuk `url(r'^delete', views.delete, name="delete"), `

Comment: You need to pass the ID to the delete method through your URL. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382664/python-django-delete-current-object for an example.

Comment: @aus_lacy Deleting objects using a GET argument is almost always a bad idea. The question owner's method is more correct (but a bit buggy) here. See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are `POST`ing your object id through a form while your `delete` view expects it as an argument (`my_id`). Change it to:

```
def delete(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        my_id = request.POST.get('id')
        Deleted=get_object_or_404(Document, id=my_id)
        ...
```

As a side note, the Python convention is to use lowercase names for objects. Consider renaming `Deleted` to `deleted`.

**Update**: You also seem to have omitted to include the `id` of the object to be deleted in your form. Put the following line somewhere between your `<form>` and `</form>` tags:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ document.id }}" />
```

Comment: Thank you!  I can now get into the delete method!  However, I'm now triggering `Page not found (404)` while in the method.  Why would it not be able to retrieve the image?

Comment: sorry forgot to tag @Selcuk.