# Is it possible to view, modify, delete data in one specific gridView(dataset) with Django?

Tags: python, django, gridview

With C# for instance, you can bind data from a table to a dataset and display it in a gridview where you can edit the data directly. The dataset can actually  contain an entire database table for instance. Is it possible to do the same with Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but that is not the way that Django works, is too much work and resources render all that data in one single page, you can for example add buttons for each one, to view, to edit, to delete

Comment: Thank you. How should proceed with the button? Should I make it a link that sends an argument to a view supposed to delete or modify the record?

Comment: You can  create a view that delete by the id of the object, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382664/python-django-delete-current-object, and about edit an existing object read about instance https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform